# What is the best way i can obtain a twitter List/Group XML feed?

Tags: xml

I know you can use https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/< user >.xml for a users status feed but i dont know how I can get statuses from a user's twitter list/group.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

after spending a very long time on google trying to find an answer to my question, I landed this http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/the-incredibly-painful-way-of-getting-an-rss-feed-of-a-twitter-list hopefully it will help others with a similar question

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I would do it using C#

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/< user >.xml");
    List<string> statusTexts = doc.Root.Elements("status")
                                    .Elements("text")
                                    .Select(t => t.Value)
                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: well, im trying to get status feeds from a twitter List/group in xml or json format. thanks for trying though

Comment: What i want to get is the status feed timeline for members of a specified twitter group/list.

Comment: after spending a very long time on google trying to find an answer to my question, I landed this [link](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/the-incredibly-painful-way-of-getting-an-rss-feed-of-a-twitter-list)
hopefully it will help others with a similar question

Comment: @James post your solution as an answer so it's visible and I'll delete my answer.